# Is there a big gain replacing DISTINCT with GROUP BY

Tags: sql-server

Without any definite proof I've been preferring to use the following to get a distinct list of `x`:

```
SELECT  x
FROM    tb_containRepeatedX
GROUP BY x
```

As opposed to

```
SELECT  DISTINCT x
FROM    tb_containRepeatedX
```

Is this the correct strategy?

Comment: Check the executions plan.  They are probably identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the execution plan. It's the same,

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c3e7a/11)

With GROUP:

[image]

With DISTINCT:

[image]

Comment: that's really surprising!